# Retrofit post and get at the same time?

Tags: php, android, mysql, retrofit2

I have an insert query set up with retrofit which works successfully. I am trying to ammend it as after the insert is doneI need it to give me the row ID PK to send back to the android app.

I have the php set up to obtain this ID right after the insert and its stored in the Json array. However I do not know how to process this back through retrofit during one action.

PHP CODE :

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO Cbt ( userId, therapistId, moodBefore,   automaticThought, distortions, challengeThought, alternativeThought, moodAfter, posted) VALUES
('$userId','$therapistId','$moodBefore','$automaticThought', NULL,  '$challengeThought', '$alternativeThought', NULL, '$posted')";

  $resultinsert = $conn -> query($insert);
              if(!$resultinsert){
                  echo $conn->error;
        }

      $cbtId = $conn->insert_id;

        $json_array = array();
        $json_array[] =$cbtId;
        echo json_encode($json_array);
```

This code is tested and works. It inserts the row and returns the rowID PK.

JAVA CODE :

```
 Call<ResponseBody> call = RetrofitClient
                        .getInstance()
                        .getApi()
                        .insertLog(userId, therapistId, moodBefore, automaticThoughtString, distortions, challengeThoughtString, alternativeThoughtString, moodAfter, posted);

                call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                    }
                });
```

This is the code for the insert which works. How can I ammend this code to capture that cbtId which is returned in the php after the insert?

Comment: You have to update Retrofit to use String as a returned value instead of ResponseBody. The value would be available using the `call` variable in he `OnResponse` method.

Comment: I updated Retrofit to String, when I type call in the OnResponse body what comes after  call? call.tostring()? how to I capture that row id into an int?

Comment: Cannot get this to work at all :( can't go any further until I make this work

Comment: I would have said the `response` object, sorry about my mistake. Use `response.body()` to have the string you want.